# 3ds max biped for unity ragdoll

Tags: unity-game-engine, max, 3ds, ragdoll

I am trying to go through rag-doll wizard of unity 4, It need elbow and knee joints, but 3dsmax biped object dont have knee and elbow, I tried to put upper arm as elbow and upper leg as knee, but resulted rag-doll is twisting wrong ways.

How can i add knee and elbow in 3dsmax biped ? or how can i make unity ragdoll work with default 3ds max biped skelton ?

I cant really find anything about this topic anywhere. i am sure i am doing something very stupid which no one ever did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the forearm and lower leg as elbow and knee respectively.

Comment: yea that works actually. the problem was the collider of upper legs, they were coliding with each other resulting a quick bounce and then weird rotation, i disabled upper leg colliders and seems working ok